# Prove that for a homogeneous function of degree one all directional derivatives exist

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I am trying to prove that for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is homogeneous of degree one, all directional derivatives exist. I also want to prove that it is differentiable if and only if $f$ is linear.

I know that since the function is homogeneous, I have $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ for $\lambda>0$ and $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but don't know how to continue from this.

Comment: You mean, every directional derivative **at (0,0)**, right?

Comment: Well, I think I would want to give a prove for every point, but I guess the origin would be a good start. Can it be proved in general, you think?

Comment: It is false at every point not (0,0).

Comment: Why does it turn out false outside (0,0)?

Comment: Because there are counterexamples that are nowhere continuous except at (0,0).

Comment: Could you provide a proof for the origin, since this is still unclear to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39529/discussion-between-falidoro-and-did).

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\ne (a,b)=h\in\mathbb{R}^2$ a direction. $f(0,0)=0\cdot f(1,0)=0$.

$(Df)(0,0)(h)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f((0,0)+t(a,b))-f(0,0)}{\left \| (a,b) \right \|} =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(ta,tb)}{t\cdot\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t\cdot f(a,b)}{t\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a,b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{f(a,b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Comment: (+1) I wonder why it was downvoted. Perhaps because of the ambiguity of your notation $Df$ for the directional derivative, since this $Df$ usually denotes the differential? Or because of your harmless restriction $n=2$?